# Auto scroll a webpage with rss-feed, item by item

Tags: javascript, php, html, rss, autoscroll

I'm making a wallboard (monitor with a newsfeed on it). I'm new to javascript but managed to find a few sources that helped me to put an RSS-feed on a PHP-page and format it with CSS.
So far so good! 
To turn this page into a wallboard, I'd like to show one feed-item for a few seconds and then have to page automatically scroll to the next item. Each feed-item is in a `<div class="post">`.
Could someone please help me with some sample autoscroll code?

I've tried to scroll continuously through the page, but that is not the effect that I'm looking for.

This is the code of a `<div>` that shows a post:

```
<div class="post">
<div class="post-head">
<h2><a class="feed_title" href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></h2>
<span><?php echo $pubDate; ?></span>
</div>
<div class="post-content">
<?php echo implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $description), 0, 20)) . "..."; ?> <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">Read more</a>
</div>
</div>
```

To scroll, I currently use a script from javascriptkit.com:

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">

var currentpos=0,alt=1,curpos1=0,curpos2=-1
function initialize(){
startit()
}
function scrollwindow(){
if (document.all)
temp=document.body.scrollTop
else
temp=window.pageYOffset
if (alt==0)
alt=1
else
alt=0
if (alt==0)
curpos1=temp
else
curpos2=temp
if (curpos1!=curpos2){
if (document.all)
currentpos=document.body.scrollTop+1
else
currentpos=window.pageYOffset+1
window.scroll(0,currentpos)
}
else{
currentpos=0
window.scroll(0,currentpos)
}
}
function startit(){
setInterval("scrollwindow()",100)
}
window.onload=initialize
</script>
```

The page that I have now is available here:
https://app-storage.org/mrm/rsstest.php

The effect I'm looking for is:
1. Show the first news item
2. wait a few seconds
3. smoothly scroll to the second news item
4. at the end of the page, return to the first item

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!